# Connect 4 using the board

Tags: java, arrays

We're currently programming a little Connect 4 game without any GUI. I have problems with using the board to fill in the chips ('X's or 'O's). I made a char array to draw a board as told in the instructions and am clueless how I fill the board with the chips. Here's my Code:

```
char player = 'X';
    char[][] board = new char[7][8];    
    public void sBoard()
    {
        char[][] board = new char[7][8];
        for (int i=0;i<board.length-1;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("|");

            for (int j=0;j<board[i].length-1;j++)
            {
                board[i][j]='.';
                System.out.print(board[i][j]+"|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

This creates a board and with dots all over it, now Player 1 and 2 will fill it with either X or O.

```
public void userInput() {
        System.out.print("Which coloumn? (1-7): ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = in.nextInt();
        in.close();
        for (int i = feld.length; i >0; i--) {


                if (board[i][ein-1] == '.') {
                    if (player == 'X') {
                        board[board.length - 2][ein - 1] = 'X';
                        System.out.print(board[board.length-2][input-1]);
                    }
                    if (player == 'O') {
                        board[board.length - 2][ein - 1] = 'O';
                        System.out.print(input[board.length-2][input-1]);
                    }
                    if (player == 'O')
                        player = 'X';
                    else
                        player = 'O';
            }
            System.out.println();
```

Now since the char array was filled in

> Spielfeld,
>    method, the array is obviously empty when I want to fill it with X or O. Is there a way to have the whole 2D array (values) copied into the bEingabe method? If there's any workaround/other way to solve this I'd appreciate it.

EDIT: Translated all the variables in English. To give you a vague idea what it does: It basically "throws" X or O(beginning with X) into the user inputed coloumns ranging from 1-7

Comment: Let me give you a tip - don't waste your time on this. It is simply not worth it. Unless you are specifically told to make console game, you are far more better off learning some basics in GUI such as SWING and go from there. Back in a day I made a snake game in similar way, and looking back to it I regret the time I spent, as it had no value for me regarding future problems, as well as it was way harder to make than a GUI counterpart.

Comment: I disagree about learning "some basics in GUI"; that might be useful enough, but if you're just learning the language, then I think this exercise can help you do that, and be useful even if you don't use anything else from it again.  Unfortunately, I am having trouble reading the code because the names are not in English, so it is difficult for me to tell what's what.

Comment: If you are just learning the language, there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: @arcy I apologise. I completely forgot about the variables. I changed them to english. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some aspects to notice:

---

- You define/overload variable *board* in two scopes, one global and one local.

One option is to set the global one in the local method:

```
char[][] board = new char[7][8];

public void sBoard()
{
 board = new char[7][8];
 ...
```

Another option is to return it by

```
public char[][] board() {
   ...
   return board;
}
```

and use it by

```
void bEingabe(char[][] board) {...}
```

---

- Don't close System.in early, if you want to read from it again after, as you can't access it anymore.

  `in.close();`

Better close it, when game's over, i.e. at the end of the main()

---

- You translated not enough, as your code doesnt compile in the current form.

---

As it is probably an assignment from school, it's fine to  implement this, learning java basics imo.

EDIT(sorry for the many, its very difficult to format it on mobile):

And it seems you're a german student, so maybe teach yourself little bits about scopes:
http://www.scalingbits.com/java/javakurs1/methoden/variablen-sichtbarkeit-lokal-global